# Lambda and cast intersection type (Eclipse compiler bug)

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

So, why does this code compile?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator test = (Calculator & Sumator) (a, b) -> a + b;
    System.out.println(test.calculate(2, 3));

    Sumator sumator = (Calculator & Sumator) (a, b) -> a + b; // does compile, but throws an Exception
    sumator.test();

    Both both = (Both) (a, b) -> a + b; // does not compile
}

interface Calculator {
    public int calculate(int a, int b);
}

interface Sumator {
    public int test();

    public int test3(int a, int b);
}

// intersection of both types
interface Both extends Sumator, Calculator {

}
```

This is sort of misleading, I do know about casting to an intersection type, I've read the jls, but still confusing.

It sort of makes sense why

```
 Serializable & Comparable
```

would compile, since the result (the synthetic type) between those two is a functional interface, but why does :

```
 Calculator & Sumator
```

works? That synthetic type is not a functional interface.

Comment: Which `JDK` do you use? It doesn't compile in all cases.

Comment: @Andremoniy 1.8.0_45

Comment: It gives `multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface INT#1
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,Calculator,Sumator`

Comment: @Andremoniy you're right. Seems like a eclipse compiler issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/487586) which has been fixed for milestone 6 towards Eclipse Neon (4.6).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like an Eclipse compiler bug probably, because it does not compile under javac. I wonder how to fix this or if there is already an issue opened for this.

```
   MultipleCastsBound.java:5: error: incompatible types: INT#1 is not a functional interface
        Calculator test = (Calculator & Sumator) (a, b) -> a + b;
                                                 ^
    multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface INT#1
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,Calculator,Sumator
MultipleCastsBound.java:8: error: incompatible types: INT#1 is not a functional interface
        Sumator sumator = (Calculator & Sumator) (a, b) -> a + b;
                                                 ^
    multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface INT#1
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,Calculator,Sumator
2 errors
```

Comment: You should explicitly mention about that it is Eclipse compiling problem in your question. And also you should always check compilation issues with original JDK compiler

Comment: @Andremoniy yup, I feel pretty stupid for not doing that, your comment made my "aha moment". Thank you

Comment: Please add Eclipse version (or JDT plugin version) to the question or to the answer. This might help further readers.