# ClassCastException when capturing a serializable lambda with intersection type parameters

Tags: lambda, java-8, intersection, classcastexception, type-variables

I've replicated an exception thrown when attempting to use type variable type intersection to capture lambdas; specifically, to replicate, I attempted to catch a lambda as `F` where `<A, F extends Consumer<A> & Serializable>`:

```
public class Consumers {

    public static <A, F extends Consumer<A> & Serializable>
    Consumer<A> serializable(F action) {
        return action;
    }

    public static <A> Consumer<A> vary(Consumer<? super A> action) {...}

    private static final Consumer<Object> DOES_NOTHING =
            serializable(a -> {});

    public static <A> Consumer<A> doesNothing() {
        return vary(DOES_NOTHING);
    }

    ...
}

Consumer<String> action = Consumers.doesNothing(); // throws class cast exception
```

The following is an example of the exception thrown:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [insert lambda name] cannot be cast to java.util.function.Consumer
```

I'm able to use `Consumers.serializable` with local or instance variables; this exception is thrown when trying to initialize static variables.

Is this correct behavior? I'm using the latest Eclipse Oxygen, JDK u112.

Comment: The eclipse compiler is a different one than the JDK's and there are quite a few differences in how they behave. Maybe give it a try using JDK's compiler? `javac` or maven or whatever you use that uses JDK's compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be allowed: `javac` complains:

```
Consumers.java:??: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) A,F
            serializable(a -> {});
                        ^
    (argument mismatch; Consumer<Object> cannot be converted to INT#1)
  where A,F are type-variables:
    A extends Object declared in method <A,F>serializable(F)
    F extends Consumer<A>,Serializable declared in method <A,F>serializable(F)
  where INT#1 is an intersection type:
    INT#1 extends Object,Serializable,Consumer<Object>
```

It is actually an Eclipse compiler [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487586), fixed in 4.6 M6 (Neon), and it has already been noticed in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268927/lambda-and-cast-intersection-type-eclipse-compiler-bug).

Comment: Yeah; I just used javac and received the same error; Oxygen compiles this, but throws an exception. Although, what differs from the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268927/lambda-and-cast-intersection-type-eclipse-compiler-bug) you linked is that Consumer is a SAM and Serializable is a ZAM; you would think that this would compile (javac) or not throw an exception (Eclipse Oxygen). It seems odd that `(Consumer<A> & Serializable)` catches lambdas but `<T extends Consumer<A> & Serializable> ... (T arg)` does not (but only for static fields); I'll mark this answer. Thanks.